# Neo4J : Force relationship constrains

Tags: neo4j

I have two type of objects say
     Entity and Type.

Each entity can be of of one Type only.

So

```
 Merge (M1:Entity {name:'m1'})
 Merge (M2:Entity {name:'m2'})
 Merge (T1:EType {name:'System'})
 Merge (T2:EType {name:'User'})
```

Then

```
MERGE (M1)-[:typeOf]->(T1) 
MERGE (M2)-[:typeOf]->(T1)
```

should work, but following one should give me error ( Each entity should be linked with only one EType)

```
MERGE (M1)-[:typeOf]->(T2)
```

What I need is to provide constrains on the schema level.

Answer (score 0):

As of Neo4j 3.1, the only supported schema constraints are:

- Uniqueness constraint on label/property
- Existence constraint on label/property (enterprise edition only)
- Existence constraint on relationship type/property (enterprise edition only)

There is no schema support for the restriction you want.

That said, there are [workarounds you'll have to code yourself](https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/), such as by adding a TransactionEventHandler to enforce your requirements.